# display records in a comma seperated values in the final row, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

### **Format**

9XSA 
ASX9

How can I display the records seperated by comma seperated values in the final row ? using a  'SELECT' query ?

the result should be

### **Format**

9XSA 
ASX9,9XSA

if there are three records for instance, then

### **Format**

9XSA 
7BSF 
ASX9,9XSA,7BSF

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CSV = ''

SELECT @CSV = @CSV + ',' + Field1 FROM Table1

SET @CSV = RIGHT(@CSV, LEN(@CSV)-1)

SELECT Field1 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT @CSV
```